# How would the process tree look having a code using fork()-C

Tags: c, process, tree

I have the following code written in C and I would like to know how the process tree drawing looked like.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=1;j++){
        fork();
        printf("Hello");
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using lists works well for mapping logical trees..

Comment: If you print pids and ppids along `hello`, I'm pretty sure that you will be able to reconstruct the tree, just add a call to `sleep()` after the loops to prevent orphaned processes...

Comment: If you are on Linux, add `sleep()` after `fork()` and use program `pstree` to visualize the process tree.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use 'ps' (on linux) or 'tasklist' (on windows) command to check? For example,

ps -ef f

Comment: I just took an example, so how about "ps -ef f"

Comment: Sorry, I was busy at that time and didn't have time to check.